# Oracle views with no affect of underlying table structure changes

Tags: oracle, view

I need to create a view over a table and would not wish to change view each time table structure changes. Is there any such possibility? any pointers appreciated around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to specify all the fields of your table, you can define a view with something like `select *`, even if I don't like such solution, but you always have to rebuild your view after a table alter.
For example:

```
SQL> create table yourTable ( a number, b number);
Table created.

SQL> insert into yourTable values ( 1, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into yourTable values ( 10, 20);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace view yourView as select * from yourTable;

View created.
```

The view works fine:

```
SQL> select * from yourView;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2
        10         20
```

If you add a column, the view will not show it:

```
SQL> alter table yourTable add (c number);

Table altered.

SQL> select * from yourView;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2
        10         20
```

You need to rebuild your view to have the new column:

```
SQL> create or replace view yourView as select * from yourTable;

View created.

SQL> select * from yourView;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2
        10         20
```

If you drop a column, your view will become invalid, and you need to rebuild it:

```
SQL> alter table yourTable drop column c;

Table altered.

SQL> select * from yourView;
select * from yourView
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: view "ALEK.YOURVIEW" has errors


SQL> create or replace view yourView as select * from yourTable;

View created.

SQL> select * from yourView;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         1          2
        10         20
```